# how to create single link in zoomcharts even though there are multiiple links between two nodes but all the link details must be available

Tags: zoomcharts

```
var data = {
    "nodes": [{
        "id": "n1",
        "loaded": true,
        "style": {
            "label": "Node1"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "n2",
        "loaded": true,
        "style": {
            "label": "Node2"
        }
    }],
    "links": [{
        "id": "l1",
        "from": "n1",
        "to": "n2",
        "style": {
            "fillColor": "red",
            "toDecoration": "arrow"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "l11",
        "from": "n1",
        "to": "n2",
        "style": {
            "fillColor": "red",
            "toDecoration": "arrow"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "l111",
        "from": "n1",
        "to": "n2",
        "style": {
            "fillColor": "red",
            "toDecoration": "arrow"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "l114",
        "from": "n1",
        "to": "n2",
        "style": {
            "fillColor": "red",
            "toDecoration": "arrow"
        }
    }]
};
var t = new NetChart({
    container: document.getElementById("demo"),
    area: {
        height: 350
    },
    data: {
        preloaded: data
    },
    info: {
        enabled: true,
        linkContentsFunction: function(data, link, callback) {
            return link.id;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered on zoomcharts forum:

https://forum.zoomcharts.com/t/want-single-link-connection-even-there-are-multiple-links/2072/6

Basically, you can use one of four methods:

1. use `multiLinkProcessor` method to merge the links
2. use `linkFilter` to omit certain links
3. use `linkStyle` method to apply certain link-specific styles
4. use custom `dataFunction` method to pre-process the link/node data before passing it to the success callback.